# Madiatek WIFI Card not detected, no wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, network-manager

I got a new pc and it has a mediatek wifi
I tried every kernel from 5.12 to 5.16, nothing worked.
BT works for some reason, it seems to be a driver problem not loading (checked everywhere, people made it work somehow)
The card works in windows, I'm NOT dual booting, just installed to check.

these are some info:

```
uname -a
Linux gianluca-HM90 5.15.0-051500rc6-generic #202110180730 SMP Mon Oct 18 07:33:22 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lshw -C network
*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0300000-e03fffff memory:e0400000-e0403fff memory:e0404000-e0404fff

apt info linux-firmware -a | grep Version

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
Version: 1.201.3
Version: 1.201

modinfo mt7921e | grep -i version
srcversion:     84632BD887293842C49AE99
vermagic:       5.15.0-051500rc6-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

---

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:0608]
        Subsystem: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:0608]
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller I225-V [8086:15f3] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet 

Controller I225-V [8086:0000]
```

---

```
gianluca@gianluca-HM90:~$ sudo dmesg | grep mt7
[sudo] password for gianluca: 
[   46.925321] mt76x2u 2-1.3:1.0: ASIC revision: 76120044
[   46.958324] mt76x2u 2-1.3:1.0: ROM patch build: 20141115060606a
[   47.123015] mt76x2u 2-1.3:1.0: Firmware Version: 0.0.00
[   47.123023] mt76x2u 2-1.3:1.0: Build: 1
[   47.123026] mt76x2u 2-1.3:1.0: Build Time: 201507311614____
[   47.923887] usbcore: registered new interface driver mt76x2u
[   47.941802] mt76x2u 2-1.3:1.0 wlxf07959e8d5b4: renamed from wlan0
```

gianluca@gianluca-HM90:~$ sudo dmesg | grep wlx
[sudo] password for gianluca:
[    4.947866] rtl88XXau 1-1.1.3:1.0 wlxe8de27192175: renamed from wlan0
[   17.688915] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlxe8de27192175: link becomes ready
gianluca@gianluca-HM90:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
gianluca@gianluca-HM90:~$ sudo iwlist scan
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eno1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp4s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlxe8de27192175  Scan completed :
Cell 01 - Address: 1A:72:A8:1C:55:A0
ESSID:"RealMe7"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
Mode:Master
Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
Encryption key:on
Bit Rates:390 Mb/s
Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
Group Cipher : CCMP
Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
Quality=98/100  Signal level=-40 dBm
Extra:fm=0003
Cell 02 - Address: A4:91:B1:B5:86:F9
ESSID:"FASTWEB-B586F9"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
Mode:Master
Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
Encryption key:on
Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
Group Cipher : CCMP
Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
IE: Unknown: DDAA0050F204104A0001101044000102103B000103104700108A2019E4084A546AB3AE87A20AB093391021000B546563686E69636F6C6F721023000E4D6564696141636365737320444710240016546563686E69636F6C6F72204447413431333146574210420009313834344A434D56511054000800060050F2040001101100164D656469614163636573732044474134313331465742100800020784103C0001031049000600372A000120
Quality=100/100  Signal level=-90 dBm
Extra:fm=0003
Cell 03 - Address: 14:14:59:F0:F5:CD
ESSID:"Vodafone-Cicco"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
Mode:Master
Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
Encryption key:on
Bit Rates:300 Mb/s
Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
Group Cipher : CCMP
Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
IE: Unknown: DD7D0050F204104A0001101044000102103B000103104700102D9258D95D5D8CE205EEC9AAF72967D21021000842726F6164636F6D1023000842726F6164636F6D1024000431323334104200033236371054000800060050F20400011011000A42726F6164636F6D4150100800020000103C0001031049000600372A000120
Quality=32/100  Signal level=-77 dBm
Extra:fm=0003
Cell 04 - Address: 60:83:34:0D:AC:94
ESSID:"WebCube4-2MBQ"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
Mode:Master
Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
Encryption key:on
Bit Rates:300 Mb/s
Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020000
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
Group Cipher : CCMP
Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
IE: Unknown: DD970050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010630412531019266612286083340DAC94102100064875617765691023000752544C387878781024000D45562D323031302D30392D32301042000F3132333435363738393031323334371054000800060050F20400011011000D57656243756265342D324D42511008000220081049000600372A0001201049000600372A000120
Quality=100/100  Signal level=-84 dBm
Extra:fm=0003
Cell 05 - Address: BC:0F:9A:A0:CC:70
ESSID:"TIM-72419323"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
Mode:Master
Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
Encryption key:on
Bit Rates:867 Mb/s
Extra:wpa_ie=dd1a0050f20101000050f20202000050f2020050f20401000050f202
IE: WPA Version 1
Group Cipher : TKIP
Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
Extra:
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
Group Cipher : TKIP
Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
Authentication Suites (2) : PSK unknown (4)
IE: Unknown: DD8A0050F204104A00011010440001021057000101103B00010310470010BC329E001DD811B28601BC0F9AA0CC7010210006442D4C696E6B1023000F442D4C696E6B205265706561746572102400084441502D31363230104200046E6F6E651054000800060050F2040001101100084441502D3136323010080002210C103C0001011049000600372A000120
Quality=38/100  Signal level=-66 dBm
Extra:fm=0003
Cell 06 - Address: 32:B7:09:1E:2E:CD
ESSID:"TIM-72419323"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
Mode:Master
Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
Encryption key:on
Bit Rates:1.3 Gb/s
Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020000
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
Group Cipher : CCMP
Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
IE: Unknown: DD800050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010D4B7091E2ECB2ECB9BAC132457689BAC102100035A54451023000A5A58484E2046787878781024000546787878781042000831323334353637381054000800060050F20400011011000A5A58484E204678787878100800020000103C0001031049000600372A000120
Quality=100/100  Signal level=-86 dBm
Extra:fm=0003
Cell 07 - Address: A0:BD:CD:FA:43:FD
ESSID:"SKY87718"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11AC
Mode:Master
Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
Encryption key:on
Bit Rates:1.3 Gb/s
Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
Group Cipher : CCMP
Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
IE: Unknown: DDB20050F204104A0001101044000102103B000103104700106E0D983980F236E42EB24539B2BE6E4610210003536B7910230009536B792053453231301024000553453231301042000E44363030313933433030353531391054000800060050F204000110110009536B7920534532313010080002200C103C0001021049000E00372A0001200106FFFFFFFFFFFF10580022007FC5100018F7190C08168E3CD881693E71E8296881303030303030303130000101
Quality=31/100  Signal level=-82 dBm
Extra:fm=0003
Cell 08 - Address: 38:A6:CE:3D:5F:D3
ESSID:"SKYAFDEE"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11AC
Mode:Master
Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
Encryption key:on
Bit Rates:1.3 Gb/s
Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020000
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
Group Cipher : CCMP
Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
IE: Unknown: DDB50050F204104A0001101044000102103B000103104700109FD93B71D661279260D8C70EA24937CE10210003536B7910230005454D31353010240007312E302E302E301042000E41543133353132303330303030311054000800060050F20400011011000E536B792051204D696E6920626F7810080002200C103C0001021049000E00372A0001200106FFFFFFFFFFFF10580022007FC5100018FA6DABBBE27C5767BB289D726A7CD4BC303030303032346530000101
Quality=34/100  Signal level=-70 dBm
Extra:fm=0003
Cell 09 - Address: 38:A6:CE:6F:9A:36
ESSID:"SKYF663E"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11AC
Mode:Master
Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
Encryption key:on
Bit Rates:1.3 Gb/s
Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020000
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
Group Cipher : CCMP
Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
IE: Unknown: DDB50050F204104A0001101044000102103B000103104700108994E7EE4B93F381A8A649866DC3288410210003536B7910230005454D31353010240007312E302E302E301042000E41543133353132303330303030311054000800060050F20400011011000E536B792051204D696E6920626F7810080002200C103C0001021049000E00372A0001200106FFFFFFFFFFFF10580022007FC5100018F96F437F85BE247A6BBE4658D082E78B303030303030303130000101
Quality=21/100  Signal level=-86 dBm
Extra:fm=0003
Cell 10 - Address: BC:0F:9A:A0:CC:72
ESSID:"TIM-72419323"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11AC
Mode:Master
Frequency:5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
Encryption key:on
Bit Rates:867 Mb/s
Extra:wpa_ie=dd1a0050f20101000050f20202000050f2020050f20401000050f202
IE: WPA Version 1
Group Cipher : TKIP
Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
Extra:
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
Group Cipher : TKIP
Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
Authentication Suites (2) : PSK unknown (4)
IE: Unknown: DD8A0050F204104A00011010440001021057000101103B000103104700102880288016207615A880BC0F9AA0CC7210210006442D4C696E6B1023000F442D4C696E6B205265706561746572102400084441502D31363230104200046E6F6E651054000800060050F2040001101100084441502D3136323010080002210C103C0001021049000600372A000120
Quality=64/100  Signal level=-72 dBm
Extra:fm=0003
Cell 11 - Address: 14:14:59:F0:F5:D1
ESSID:"Vodafone5GHz-Cicco"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11AC
Mode:Master
Frequency:5.3 GHz (Channel 60)
Encryption key:on
Bit Rates:1.3 Gb/s
Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
Group Cipher : CCMP
Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
IE: Unknown: DD1D0050F204104A0001101044000102103C0001031049000600372A000120
Quality=36/100  Signal level=-83 dBm
Extra:fm=0001
Cell 12 - Address: 54:83:3A:BC:D0:AA
ESSID:"Home&Life SuperWiFi-D0A9"
Protocol:IEEE 802.11AC
Mode:Master
Frequency:5.56 GHz (Channel 112)
Encryption key:on
Bit Rates:1.3 Gb/s
Extra:rsn_ie=301a0100000fac040100000fac040100000fac028c000000000fac06
IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
Group Cipher : CCMP
Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
IE: Unknown: DD310050F204104A000110104400010210470010D868D21FF1407FBF70504CDDD2B5833F103C0001031049000600372A000120
Quality=12/100  Signal level=-88 dBm
Extra:fm=0001
Cell 13 - Address: 62:45:B7:6E:0A:58
ESSID:""
Protocol:IEEE 802.11b
Mode:Master
Frequency:5.745 GHz
Encryption key:on
Bit Rates:0 kb/s
Quality=24/100  Signal level=-87 dBm
Extra:fm=0001

enxf01e341f94c3  Interface doesn't support scanning.

Although a long time user, not really that savvy on this. Never had hardware problems.
I got a fresh kubuntu install

any idea? (using usb tethering on mobile)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep mt7` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: done!    thanks for replying and the welcome))

Comment: Please add: `sudo dmesg | grep wlx` also: `rfkill list all` and finally: `sudo iwlist scan`

Comment: done!! maybe I got to mention I'm using a usb dongle to connect (configured through another one of your tutorials) :))))

Comment: Oops! I was chasing the USB and not the PCI. Sorry for my mis-step. As for the PCI: "MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:0608]" please see the duplicate.

Comment: maaaaannn :) . I spent 5 days and 5 distros and kernels and ....thank you so much. you sorted me out 2 hardware wireless connection in 2 hours :)))) much appreciated

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working! Have fun.

Comment: Hi, this morning I logged on and the pci adapter attempts to connect but disconnects contginously without being able to load any page. I'm back on the usb adapter. (I can't comment on duplicate post, not enough points)

Comment: I suggest that you start a new question and refer to this question; something like: "My wireless disconnects constantly." Include `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and `sudo dmesg | grep mt7` I'll be happy to help.